# tesseract training - gives "Cannot open input file" error

Tags: android, windows, pdf, ocr, tiff

I'm going through [this](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine) tutorial for adding new fonts to tesseract and so far I have created tiff files for my pdfs. I'm trying to run the command:

`tesseract eng.impact.exp0.tiff eng.impact.exp0 batch.nochop makebox`

but it just displays this: 
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica

Cannot open input file: eng.impact.exp0.tiff

I just can't figure out why!

I ran the following command to create the tiff file:
`convert -density 300 -depth 4 eng.impact.exp0.pdf eng.impact.exp0.tif`

**EDIT:** Hmmm, changing the -depth option to 8 instead of 4 worked. ._.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a typo in your image filename. It should be:

```
tesseract eng.impact.exp0.tif eng.impact.exp0 batch.nochop makebox
```

Comment: When I type tif instead of tiff, it gives me an Unsupported file type error!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to re-name your TIFF file:

```
mv  eng.impact.exp0.tif  eng.impact.exp0.tiff
```

and only then run tesseract:

```
tesseract eng.impact.exp0.tiff eng.impact.exp0 batch.nochop makebox
```

Comment: I just did that, and it still gives an "Unsupported image type." error!

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem and solve it.

You must first copy the image file beside of tesseract.exe and then go to that directory and open the command prompt and run your command. just this.

note: in the command prompt, you must be in the path of tesseract and image file must be in this path.